# How do I turn off the filepath that batch displays?

Tags: python, batch-file

Hello I'm currently working on a python project where I use batch.

My problem now is anytime my script runs a batch files it always shows me the path with the command that is in the file.

Here is an example:

python:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("test.bat")
```

batch:

```
echo Hello World
```

output:

```
C:\Users\[user]\OneDrive\Desktop\Python>echo Hello World 

Hello World
```

Comment: Either change the batch file content to `@echo Hello World`, or instead of running `"test.bat"`, run `cmd.exe /q /d /c "test.bat"`

Comment: to add onto what @Compo stated, simply running `echo /?` will give a solid indication of it's purpose, for example the very first line states: `Displays messages, or turns command-echoing on or off`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@echo off` to the top of your batch script to turn off printing of commands (including the path).